# Qt Creator fails to build Android library due to back slashes in NDK path

Tags: android, c++, windows, qt, android-ndk

I am trying to build by C++ library for Android on Windows 8.1 using NDK android-ndk-r10e. The library builds totally fine on Linux, but I can't get it working on Windows.

I am always getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/sh: C:android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, Qt Creator displays path to g++ as `C:android-ndk-r10e` while it is actually `C:\android-ndk-r10e`. I tried to manually edit Makefile, but it seems to re-create it every time, so my changes got discarded.

I this a known issue? How can I work around it?

(Qt version 5.4.2, Qt Creator 3.6.0)

Comment: In **Qt Creator** options dialog, try to set **Android NDK location** as `C:/android-ndk-r10e`.

Comment: It was the 1st thing I tried, doesn't work. Each time I click Apply and close the options window it falls back to C:\ again

Comment: Try to manually change files QtCreator.ini and toolChains.xml in **AppData\Roaming\QtProject**

Comment: One caveat - maybe you have another MinGW installed on your machine. Make sure you use the one that was in **Qt** package.

Comment: @AlexCohn, thanks for your great suggestions! Another mingw that comes with git was indeed a culprit. Once I removed that from my PATH everything is working fine! I'd be glad to accept this as an answer if you post it so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of other MinGW installations; **Qt Creator** installs its own MinGW, and you should use this one for **Qt**.

Comment: so I'm seeing the exact same issue, but there is no other MinGW to blame. Do you have any idea of what else could it be?

Comment: @FelipeCenteno Check that the paths you use have no spaces or other strange characters

Comment: nope no weird characters or spaces. The issue is from a coworker, and I've been trying to help. Here is the link to his question: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44574825/qt-android-ndk-no-such-file-or-directory"

Comment: Helps for me, thanks. I have path to git bin in PATH for perl, there is some cygwin and maybe mingw stuff. Problem was solved after I removed it.