# Qt - Android NDK: No such file or directory

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have been struggling with the following problem for several days. I have a project that is working great on desktop and a custom embedded device, but when I attempt to compile for Android I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/sh:
>   C:android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++:
>   No such file or directory

The NDK does exist at that location. I have tried moving the NDK to different locations, and several versions of the NDK with the same results.

Of note is the fact that the location it seems to be referencing above, C:android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++, is incorrect.  It should begin as C:\android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64, as it is listed under Tools-> Options-> Devices -> Android.  I'm not sure why it is outputting like this, but I can't imagine it outputs differently than it is used.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your `Tools-> Options-> Devices -> Android`, have you tried to manually set the path to NDK with forward slashes (**`/`**) instead of backslashes?

Comment: Yes I have.  After closing out and opening it back up, it reverts back to backslashes.

Comment: Not that I have experience with this, but next attempt would be to manually replace every backslash with two: \\

Comment: @KyleGray did you resolved it because i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to cygwin/mingw installations. For example, Qt Creator installs its own mingw and if   cygwin/mingw is installed separately, leads to this kind of issues. Try uninstall those.